# Convert Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, converters

I Have an Array into the Database like this

```
{ 0 : "Test1", 1 : "Test2", 2 : "Test3" }
```

How can i convert this into an array in PHP? Like This

```
array[0] = "Test1"
array[1] = "Test2"
array[2] = "Test3"
```

------------------------------------------ UPDATE ------------------------------------

It doesn't work with json_decode. I allredy test it (I work with xajax):

```
$value = $obj->getValue($id); //Get Array from Database
$json = $value["datas"]; //Save datas in $json
print_r($json); //Print out data in Console
print_r("\n");
var_dump(json_decode($json,true)); //Print out decoded Value in Console
```

Then it shows my in the console this message:

```
{0:"rechenzentren.png",1:"software.png"}
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font></pre>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><xjx></xjx>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Is that how the data is stored. What datatype / dbms are you using? Is it a dedicated json data type or should you instead normalize your data instead?

Comment: its not a json string, its a normal string

Comment: How did you get the string in this format in the first place?

Comment: I solved the Problem. I have made a Array, then encode as json, save in Database, then decode json string :)

Comment: There you go, you've discovered the Sane Way™.

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = '{ 0 : "Test1", 1 : "Test2", 2 : "Test3" }';
$text = preg_replace('/(\d+)\s*:/ism', '"$1":', $text);
$array = json_decode($text, true);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a Json string, so :

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Result :

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `json_decode`, but the name must be enclosed in double quotes

```
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz" }';
var_dump(json_decode($bad_json, true)); // NULL
```

Comment: It doesn't work with json_decode. I allredy test it (I work with xajax):

    $value = $obj->getValue($id); //Get Array from Database
    $json = $value["datas"]; //Save datas in $json
    print_r($json); //Print out data in Console
    print_r("\n");
    var_dump(json_decode($json,true)); //Print out decoded Value in Console

Then it shows my in the console this message:

    {0:"rechenzentren.png",1:"software.png"}
    <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font></pre>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><xjx></xjx>

Comment: I said that name must be enclosed in double quotes. So you need replace name with preg_replace.